# Paginacion con Stored Procedure y Cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Tengo una función en la que listo mis registros con un Store Procedure y de eso quiero realizar una paginación, claro que en este caso no puedo usar la función predefinida de CakePHP aquí mi código:

```
public function index() {
$id_user = $this->Auth->user('id_usuario');
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$query_user = $connection->execute('CALL ser_get_list_persons(:_IdUser)',[':_IdUser'=>$id_user])->fetchAll('assoc');
$this->set('persons', $query_user);
```

}

A esto quiero ponerle una paginación y tendría que ser manual o tal vez aya otra forma, he buscado en toda la red pero no he encontrado algo similar por varios días por ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 0):

construí un procedimiento almacenado que hace la paginación directamente en SQL Server, pienso que es eficiente ya que le dejo todo el trabajo duro al motor, espero te sirva también:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SPS_Consultar','P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE SPS_Consultar
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SPS_Consultar
    @Tabla sysname,
    @StringABuscar VARCHAR(100) = '%%', 
    @Esquema sysname = 'dbo', 
    @NumPagina as int = 1,
    @TamPagina as int = 10,
    @OrdenarPor as varchar(100) = '',
    @Columnas  as varchar(max) ='',
    @CantPaginas INT OUT,
    @TotalRegistos INT OUT
AS
DECLARE @sqlCommand Nvarchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500) = ''
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; 

    --------------------- INICIACIÓN DE VARIABLES -----------------------
    IF @StringABuscar  = '' SET @StringABuscar = '%%'
    SET @CantPaginas = 0
    SET @TotalRegistos = 0
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    --------------------- SI @OrdenarPor ESTÁ VACÍO ---------------------
    IF @OrdenarPor = '' 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @OrdenarPor = COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Esquema
        AND TABLE_NAME = @Tabla 
        --AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar')
    END
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --------------------- CONSTRUCCIÓN DE LA CONSULTA -------------------------
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER(),* FROM [' + @Esquema + '].[' + @Tabla + '] WHERE ' 
    SET @sqlCommand = ' FROM [' + @Esquema + '].[' + @Tabla + '] WHERE ' 
    IF @Columnas = ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''' + @StringABuscar + ''' OR '
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Esquema
        AND TABLE_NAME = @Tabla 
        --AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar')
        SET @sqlCommand = left(@sqlCommand,len(@sqlCommand)-3)
        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand+' ORDER BY '+@OrdenarPor
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''' + @StringABuscar + ''' OR '
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Esquema
        AND TABLE_NAME = @Tabla 
        AND COLUMN_NAME IN (SELECT WORD FROM dbo.FNS_EXPLODE (@Columnas,','))
        SET @sqlCommand = left(@sqlCommand,len(@sqlCommand)-3)
        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand+' ORDER BY '+@OrdenarPor
    END

    SET @sqlCommand=@sqlCommand+' OFFSET ('+CAST(@NumPagina AS VARCHAR)+'-1)*'+CAST(@TamPagina AS VARCHAR)+' ROWS '
    SET @sqlCommand=@sqlCommand+' FETCH NEXT '+CAST(@TamPagina AS VARCHAR)+'ROWS ONLY '
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --------------------- CONTAR LOS REGISTROS DE LA TABLA ---------------------
    DECLARE @sqlCommand2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT @TotalRegistos = COUNT(*) OVER() ' + @sqlCommand;  
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@TotalRegistos int OUTPUT';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand2, @ParmDefinition, @TotalRegistos=@TotalRegistos OUTPUT;
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --------------------- CANTIDAD DE PAGINAS TOTALES ---------------------
    SELECT @CantPaginas = (@TotalRegistos / @TamPagina) + CASE WHEN @TotalRegistos % @TamPagina > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    --------------------- EJECUTAR CONSULTA FINAL CONSTRUIDA ---------------------
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * ' + @sqlCommand
    PRINT @sqlCommand
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlCommand
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

END
GO
```

Y lo puedes usar así:

```
DECLARE @CantPaginas INT 
DECLARE @TotalRegistos INT 
DECLARE @NumPagina INT = 1
EXEC dbo.SPS_Consultar 
    @Tabla = 'AFI', 
    --@Columnas = 'PrimerNombre', 
    @StringABuscar = '', 
    @NumPagina = @NumPagina, 
    @TamPagina = 100, 
    @CantPaginas = @CantPaginas OUTPUT, 
    @TotalRegistos = @TotalRegistos OUTPUT

PRINT 'PÁGINA ' + CAST(@NumPagina AS VARCHAR) + ' DE '+CAST(@CantPaginas AS VARCHAR)
PRINT 'Total Registros '+CAST(@TotalRegistos AS VARCHAR)
```